# How to create a storm swath map?

Tags: qgis

I can't really find the words to explain what I'd like to achieve so I attached a picture.

[image]

The top picture was made of two layers, the layer with circles was made/styled using the instructions from an answer to a question that I posted a few days ago [(How to scale with radius attribute)](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/111417?redirect=1). The other layer was created by converting that same layer using the Points to Paths plugin. The bottom image is what I want to achieve. For background info, the data is about wind information from typhoon Haiyan that struck the Philippines last November 2013. I want to get/generate the storm swath (**the lower picture from the image above**) that kind of look like the screenshot that I took from [USAID](http://usaid.maps.arcgis.com/apps/OnePane/basicviewer/index.html?appid=dc096ab716e246878df65528eae6c739) (image below).

[image: typhoon Yolanda storm swath]

How can I achieve this or is this possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks to @AlexandreNeto, after using his answer below, I also applied [auto trace plugin](http://www.lutraconsulting.co.uk/products/autotrace/) for finishing touches...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

My approach would be to:

- Create a buffer around your points using radius field;
- Union all resulting features;
- Create a new buffer of exagerated size around it (according to your data two different point seams to differs in around 20000 m, so I would use this value);
- Then create an inverse buffer of it (-20000m);
- might need to simplify the result.

I think this would do what you need.

keep in mind that having your data in spatialite or Postgis would allow this operations "on the fly"

Also using Postgis You could go with alpha shapes or concave hulls.

## **UPDATE: step by step instructions**

Lets assume that that your point layer is called "haiyan", and that one of the fields is  called "RADIUS(m)" and is already in EPGS:3857 (you can't use the original WGS84 since it will consider your radius meter as degrees). At this point it does not matter where it is saved.

### 1. Create the first buffer and dissolve

- Go to Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer(s);
- As input vector layer use the "haiyan";
- Select the buffer distance field option and choose "RADIUS";
- Tick the dissolve buffers results box;
- Set the destination for the output shapefile call it "haiyan_radius_buffer.shp";
- Tick the add result to canvas box;
- And OK.

[image]

You should end up with something like this:

[image]

### 2. Smooth the resulting boundaries using expanding and contracting buffers

- Go to Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer(s);

  - As input vector layer use the "haiyan_radius_buffer";
  - Set buffer distance to 231500(m);
  - Set the destination for the output shapefile call it "haiyan_expand_buffer.shp";
  - Tick the add result to canvas box;
  - And OK.

[image]

The result:

[image]

Now do the same operation on "haiyan_expand_buffer" layer but with a negative value for the buffer:

[image]

and (drums rumbling):

[image]

### Some notes:

- I underestimated the buffer value to use in my original answer, did a few tries and end up with the maximum radius as being a nice value for the expanding and contract buffers;
- You can do all this operations without closing the the Buffer(s) tool, just need to change the input layer, the buffer values and the output;
- In all buffers you can change the "segments to aproximate" value, higher values will create smoother circles but also bigger files;
- To finish, you can repeat step 2 a few time to get even smoother lines around your original radius buffers.

Comment: +1 for the buffer out/buffer in technique as a creative idea for smoothing an edge/line.

Comment: @alexandre-neto Sorry, I'm a new user to QGIS. Please bear with me. I can't get past in creating a buffer. Is this ok even if some values of radius are null? Do I need to check the dissolve buffer results? Thanks..

Comment: The result by the way looked like a concentric circle. Is this the expected result? As your per advice, I load my data in QSpatialLite and used the table as my layer. Thanks...

Comment: @euler I have noew realized that you are a new to QGIS. When I mentioned using spatialite, I was referring to use SQL statments to preform the analysis, and not only storing the data in spatialite (Tho this is also good!). "spatial" SQL it's not as easy as pressing buttons but It is a very powerful tool to learn. But maybe it's better to learn the basics before. I If are willing to have a go with SQL, I can expand my answer.

Comment: @euler. The radius fields must have some value. If you have Null Values you can, do a few different aproaches. 1 - remove the point from analysis; 2- set a value of 0 or a very small value; 3 - Estimate the missing values interpolating them from the adjacent ones. It really depends on the data you have and where the Null values are.

Comment: @AlexandreNeto, thanks for offering to expand your answer. I tried to read the QGIS user manual but I did not find examples of using buffers and union. What I would like to ask from you is to please expand your answer on the steps involved i.e. which layer should I apply the union and buffer after I applied the first buffer. Thanks in advance...